# What is the difference between giving a string and a list of string(s) to keras tokenizer?

Tags: python, keras, nlp, tokenize

I am working with `keras.preprocessing` for tokenize sentences, I encountered an unexpected case in `keras.preprocessing.text.Tokenize`. When I give it string, the output of `word_index` is a dictionary of  single characters and their indexes  but for list the output of `word_index` is dictionary of words (spllited by space).
Why this happen?
**String for tokenizer input:**

```
from keras.preprocessing.text import Tokenizer

text = "Keras is a deep learning and neural networks API by François Chollet" 
tokenizer = Tokenizer()
tokenizer.fit_on_texts(text) #input of tokenizer as string

print(tokenizer.word_index)

>>> {'e': 1, 'a': 2, 'n': 3, 'r': 4, 's': 5, 'i': 6, 'l': 7, 'o': 8, 'k': 9, 'd': 10, 'p': 11, 't': 12, 'g': 13,
     'u': 14, 'w': 15, 'b': 16, 'y': 17, 'f': 18, 'ç': 19, 'c': 20, 'h': 21}
```

**List for tokenizer input:**

```
from keras.preprocessing.text import Tokenizer

text = ["Keras is a deep learning and neural networks API by François Chollet"] 
tokenizer = Tokenizer()
tokenizer.fit_on_texts(text) #input of tokenizer as list

print(tokenizer.word_index)

>>> {'keras': 1, 'is': 2, 'a': 3, 'deep': 4, 'learning': 5, 'and': 6, 'neural': 7, 'networks': 8,
     'api': 9, 'by': 10, 'françois': 11, 'chollet': 12}
```

Answer (score 0):

The docs state to use a list of strings or a list of list of strings. There is no mention of whether you are allowed to pass a string as input, so it's possible that what you're doing is undefined behaviour that isn't getting caught.

When you pass a string as input, it looks like Keras interprets it to be a character level tokenization. Either way, if you wanted to perform a character level tokenization, it's much better to pass `char_level=True` when you are instantiating the `Tokenizer` class.

TL;DR: Don't pass a string. The [docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/preprocessing/text/Tokenizer) don't mention it as a legal argument. There exists a legal way of performing character level tokenization.